# Trying to initialize a List with a static method, but items are null when accessed

Tags: java

I have an assignment in java where our professor gives us a test code, and we have to write the necessary classes and methods to make it work, but I'm new with java and I'm having some trouble with it. Here's my professor's code:

```
public class TestProcess {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     *  A Process is a finite sequence of Tasks
     *
     */

//part one  
    Process p = Process.getOrders(); // special process with 3 tasks 
    Task firstTaskOfProcessP = p;
    List<Task> ListTasksProcessP = p;

    assert p!=null;

    // part two
    assert p.size()==3;

    Task t1 = p.get(0); // hint: 0 means first element of the List, 1 means second, 2 means third.
    Task t2 = p.get(1); // hint: 0 means first element of the List, 1 means second, 2 means third.
    assert t1 == firstTaskOfProcessP;

}
```

The part I'm confused about is part one. I have to use a static method to initialize p instead of a regular constructor. This means that getOrders has to return a variable of type Process. At the same time though p has to be able to be assigned to a variable of type Task, and also a List of tasks. This is the code I came up with in the end:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Task<T extends Task> extends ArrayList<Task>{
    public String description;

    public Task(){
        super();
    }

    public Task(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
         return this.description;
    }
}
```

And

```
import java.util.*;

public class Process<T extends Task> extends Task<T>{

    public Process(){
        super();
    }

    public Process(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static Process<Task> getOrders(){
        ArrayList<Task> list = new Process<Task>();

        Task t1 = new Task("Routine startup task");
        Task t2 = new Task("Sending orders Task");
        Task t3 = new Task("EndingTask");

        list.add(t1);
        list.add(t2);
        list.add(t3);

        return (Process<Task>)list;
    }

    public Task get(int index){
        return (Task)this.get(index);
    }
}
```

This code compiles, however, when it reaches part two and does p.get(0) it turns out there's null inside it. Why is it null and how can I get this code to work? Also, it's my first time using static methods instead of constructors so I have no idea what I'm doing. What would be a good way to write the method getOrders?

Comment: The code you posted results in a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` because of the recursive `get` call. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: IMHO...you're new to Java and your instructor gave you code like that?  Is the guy a lunatic gone off his medication?  Nobody would ever write code that looked like that.  Taking it at face value as a crazy exercise in understanding and reverse engineering types, it seems totally inappropriate for a beginning programmer.  This might be ok in a more advanced class, but not if you're using a static method for the first time.  Yikes!

Comment: You've done pretty well with how far you've gotten.  I like your effort.  You do seem to have a pretty good understanding of what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

So not jealous of you.  The messed-up logic implies that a Process is-a Task has-a List and equals t1  (...assuming I can read this correctly).  Here's an equally messed-up way to satisfy the assertions.  Good luck.

```
interface Task  { }

class Process extends ArrayList<Task> implements Task { 
   static Process taskList = new Process ();

    public static Process getOrders () {
        taskList.add(taskList);
        taskList.add(new Process ());
        taskList.add(new Process ());

        return taskList;
}}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Bravo!  I might have been able to come up with this too, but maybe not.  Very nice.  So a nice answer to a totally insane question.